# What does it mean when someone say "He is politically correct?"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am often hearing in the office that someone says this sentence "He is politically correct?".  What's the difference between "He is correct" and "He is politically correct?".

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161941/how-has-the-meaning-of-politically-correct-changed

Comment: I'd advise thinking of 'politically correct' as a compound adjective, rather than modifier + adjective. The sense of 'politically' in the expression is quite different from that in say 'politically active' or 'politically organised'. [WordNet 3.0](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/politically) contrasts the usages: _politically_ 
Adv. 1. _with regard to social relationships involving authority_ "politically correct clothing"
2. _with regard to government_  "politically organized units" **but** the usage it lists as the more common is rare outside the compound 'politically correct'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Politically correct" suggests that the statement, action, form of attire, etc. conforms to socially accepted norms with the further suggestion that the speaker, actor or wearer does not fully endorse the issue at hand.

Comment: I think it is not a matter of conforming to "socially accepted norms", but of conforming (or paying lip service to) certain attitudes & behaviors which the left/liberal segment of society would like to see become socially accepted norms.

Comment: I think political correctness has moved beyond "left/liberal."  It is certainly not "politically correct" to question American exceptionalism, military overreach or the utter absence of voter fraud, among many other tropes of the right/conservative segment of society.